# Load database table as IOption<> at startup

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, configuration

.Net Core 3.1 application.  ConfigureServices in Startup.cs sets up an EF Core 5 DbContext.  One of the "static" tables I wish to load into memory and make available via a AddOptions to make the table injectible throughout the application (cheap man's caching). Same as BINDing from appsettings but using an EF Core database.

I already "seed" the database in Main by creating a scope and getting the DbContext service to run an initialization method. That technique won't work in this case because I am adding a service. Is there a way to read the DbContext while I am still in ConfigureServices? A way to add a service once the Host is built but not run?

How would *you* approach this?

Comment: The simple solution is to not use DI for any DbContext you need at startup; just "new one up" in a `using` block. Also this pattern is required when your DI DbContext is configured based on data in the current request (eg multi-tenant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't you know.  I post the question and kept reframing my search terms and digging and voila.

[Using IConfigureOptions](https://andrewlock.net/access-services-inside-options-and-startup-using-configureoptions/)

So I created a class

```
using MyContexts;
using MyModels;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Linq;
public class LoadMySettings : IConfigureOptions<MySettings>
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
    public LoadMySettings(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }
    public void Configure(MySettings options)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;
            using (var dbContext = provider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>())
            {
                options.MySettingsList = dbContext.MySettingsTable.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and embedded this in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<MySettinmgs>, LoadMySettings>();
```